# JS increase index number array by function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I trying to make a small text based rpg game, but I came across array in js and then I came to problems, I failing to increase the index number by using i instead of 0 like `myArray[i]`

I made a jsfiddle so you guys can see what I mean.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y3293r0/)

When you press the button til you get a warming, it should increase the i to 2, but it don't, but still comes  with warming and increasing the attack variable.

Comment: I dont fully understand what you want, but your `attackUp` function does `var i = 0;`

Comment: I want to increase the xpforlevel[i] by 1 every time I hit over the xp I need to level.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your code really should be posted *here*. There are facilities that allow you to make "snippets" of code that often are sufficiently functional that you don't need an offsite service like jsfiddle at all, though a jsfiddle link is OK. But the code should be at least posted as static code in the question itself here.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `attackUp` function:

```
function attackUp(){
    var i = 0;
    var attackCost = xpforlevel[i];
    if (attackCost < attackxp) {
        alert("WARMING!");
        attack++;                           
          document.getElementById('attack').innerHTML = attack;
        i++;
        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = i;
    }
}
```

Notice that your `var i = 0` statement doesn't really make sense (because everytime `attackUp` is called, `i` will be reset to `= 0` at the beginning). To fix that, erase this `var i = 0` statement from your function and put in the beginning of your JS code:

```
var i = 0;
var attackxp = 0;
var attack = 1;
```

Further, your function will only update `i` **if** `attackCost < attackxp`, otherwise it will change nothing. You need to put the `i++;` statement outside your if-block, like this:

```
function attackUp(){
    //erase this line: var i = 0;
    var attackCost = xpforlevel[i];
    i++; //added this line
    if (attackCost < attackxp) {
        alert("WARMING!");
        attack++;                           
          document.getElementById('attack').innerHTML = attack;
        //erase this line: i++;
        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your i is a local variable, it is initiated as 0 every time you call attackUp(). You should put it besides attackxp and attack.

For more information about the scope of variable in JavaScript, see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).